# dropdownlistfor + jquery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate, html.dropdownlistfor

I am creating an application in asp .net mvc3 c#. I create a dropdown list but I am unable to do a client side validation using Jquery.

I have looked at numerous articles related to it and know that this is a bug in asp .net mvc3. However, none of the work arounds have worked for my case.

My code is below:

Entity

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Furnishing is required.")]
[Display(Name = "Furnishing*")]
public int FurnishedType { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property.FurnishedType)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Property.FurnishedType, Model.FurnishedTypes, "--Select One--")
</div>
<div class="editor-field add-property-error">            
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property.FurnishedType)
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddProperty()
{
    AddPropertyViewModel viewModel = new AddPropertyViewModel
    {
        ...
        FurnishedTypes = websiteRepository.GetFurnishedTypeSelectList(-1),
        ...
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetFurnishedTypeSelectList(int selectedId)
{
    return db.FurnishedType
        .OrderBy(x => x.FurnishedTypeDescription)
        .ToList()
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.FurnishedTypeId.ToString(),
            Text = x.FurnishedTypeDescription
        });
}
```

There is a database which has values as below

```
1 Furnished
2 Part Furnished
...
```

which is used to populate the select list.

Now, this is a required field but I am unable to do a client side validation to see if the user chooses any value?
Any help would be grateful

Comment: Do you have <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> in your web.config? Can you verify that the <select> has the data-val attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you assign -1 to "--select one--"

There is something should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function (e) {
        if($("select").val()==="-1"){
           e.preventDefault();
           // display error msg beside ddl too
      }
    });
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion would be to do the following

**In the View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProperty", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{ 
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property.FurnishedType)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Property.FurnishedType, Model.FurnishedTypes)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field add-property-error">            
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property.FurnishedType)
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.validator.addMethod('selectNone', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || value != -1;
    }, "Furnishing is required.");


     $("#myForm").validate({
         rules: { FurnishedType: { selectNone: true }}
     });

</script>
```

**In the Controller**

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetFurnishedTypeSelectList(int selectedId)
{
    List<SelectListItem> Lists = new List<SelectListItem>();
    Lists = db.FurnishedType
        .OrderBy(x => x.FurnishedTypeDescription)
        .ToList()
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.FurnishedTypeId.ToString(),
            Text = x.FurnishedTypeDescription
        });

    Lists.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select One--", Value = "-1" });

    return Lists;
}
```